# Invoke command with IP address as Target server does not works at all

Tags: powershell

Please see the following command and with Trusted Hosts enabled, this does not work:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <IP address> -port 5985 -Credential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('Domain\User', (ConvertTo-SecureString 'passwd' -AsPlainText -Force))) -Authentication CredSSP -ScriptBlock {Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010;Get-Mailbox}
```

This works well when Computername is a hostname. The IP address does not works at all

Comment: Can you post the exact commands you try, and what error you're getting?

Comment: Could you post the contents of `WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts` - sanitized of course?

Comment: Because Kerberos.

Answer (score 2):

This is documented in Microsofts information here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849719.aspx

Essentially you can not use the -computername parameter with an IP without the -credential parameter as well while you can use just the -computername with a hostname.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not bound to PowerShell only commands, just download psexec from Microsoft here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/de-ch/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

This also works for older machines and for batch scripting.

Comment: PSExec has serious security vulnerabilities and should not be used in an enterprise environment, or anywhere for that matter.  This was known in 2013.

Comment: You're right about that, thanks for mentioning it.